# support python 3 on installing script for lektor

Tags: lektor

I see that [it has been merged](https://github.com/lektor/lektor/pull/207) already an year ago but the install.sh script still install with python 2.7 and all the docs still refers to python 2.7
I wonder what's the correct steps to have it working on python 3 and what's holds back for an official support?

*EDIT:* for the first part of my question on how to install, I solved by installing from git but I'm still curious to know about any plan on official support and if is possible to describe the implication of the pip installation warning on being *heavily discouraged*. what that means in practice? In travis also get deployed using pip.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a new Lektor maintainer. Lektor development had definitely slowed down shortly after that merge, and that merge didn't make it into a versioned release for a while. Sorry, about that.

I'm trying to pick development back up. In that spirit, we tagged [Lektor 3.0.1](https://github.com/lektor/lektor/releases/tag/3.0.1) on June 13, 2017, and fixed the install script you were using on the following [June 17th](https://github.com/lektor/lektor-website/commits/ca22f06a5bb673951d132571a476d1d21a904559/assets/install.sh). So, now you can use the install script, and it should work on Python 3. Please report any bugs or enhancements on [github](https://github.com/lektor/lektor/issues), or join us on [gitter](https://gitter.im/lektor/lektor) :) I absolutely want to support Python 3 for the foreseeable future, and continue to support 2.7 as long as that is practical.

Re pip: Lektor is intended to be usable by people who do not know any Python. In that spirit there are various binary installation methods. Someone in that crowd should probably not attempt to figure out how to use Lektor with pip. The binaries ought to be an easier route for that person.